# how to show that ${1\over a}={1\over b}+{1\over c}$ using the information in the figure?

Tags: geometry

Using the information in the figure, show that ${1\over a}={1\over b}+{1\over c}$
[image]

I have thought about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem , But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Ptolemy's theorem would put $a$ and $c$ on the same side, and $b$ on the other. It's possible that there is some tickery that can make it work, but at face value that doesn't seem to get you in the direction you want.

Comment: So maybe there is another way.